# CORS issue with AWS SAM deployed Lambda function

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue with a Lambda function deployed using AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model). I have implemented CORS headers in the Lambda function to handle the preflight OPTIONS request, but I'm still encountering the following error when making a request from my website:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://API_GATEWAY_URL/Prod/hello' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my Lambda function's response handling code:

```js
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

export interface LambdaResponse {
    statusCode: number;
    headers?: {
        [header: string]: string | number | boolean;
    };
    body: string;
}

interface SuccessResponse<T> {
    status: string;
    data: {
        data_type: string;
        value: T;
    };
    additional_info: string;
    timestamp: string;
}

interface ErrorInfo {
    code: number;
    error_type: string;
    field_name?: string;
    message: string;
}

interface ErrorResponse {
    status: string;
    errors: ErrorInfo[];
    additional_info: string;
    timestamp: string;
}

const allowedCorsOrigins: { [key: string]: boolean } = {
    'http://localhost:3000': true,
    'http://localhost:3001': true,
};

const generateResponse = <T>(
    statusCode: number,
    body: SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse,
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
): LambdaResponse => {
    const origin = event.headers?.Origin || event.headers?.origin || '*';

    return {
        statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': allowedCorsOrigins[origin] ? origin : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
                'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-access-token, jwt',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': origin === '*' ? 'false' : 'true',
        },
    };
};

export const sendSuccessResponse = <T>({
    event,
    data,
    dataType,
    additionalInfo = '',
}: {
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent;
    data: T;
    dataType?: string;
    additionalInfo?: string;
}): LambdaResponse => {
    const response: SuccessResponse<T> = {
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            data_type: dataType || typeof data,
            value: data,
        },
        additional_info: additionalInfo,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    return generateResponse(200, response, event);
};

export const sendErrorResponse = ({
    event,
    errorCode,
    error,
    additionalInfo = '',
}: {
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent;
    errorCode: number;
    error: { message: string; details?: ErrorInfo[] };
    additionalInfo?: string;
}): LambdaResponse => {
    const response: ErrorResponse = {
        status: 'error',
        errors: [...(error.details || [])],
        additional_info: additionalInfo,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    return generateResponse(errorCode, response, event);
};

export const unauthorizedResponse = (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, message?: string): LambdaResponse => {
    const response: ErrorResponse = {
        status: 'error',
        errors: [
            {
                code: 401,
                error_type: 'Unauthorized',
                message: message || 'Not authorized to access',
            },
        ],
        additional_info: 'Unauthorized',
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    return generateResponse(401, response, event);
};
```

This is one of my hello lambda code:

```js
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { sendErrorResponse, sendSuccessResponse } from './helper/response';
import { authenticateToken } from './helper/authenticateToken';

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        return sendSuccessResponse({
            event,
            data: {
                message: 'hello world',
                time: new Date().toISOString(),
                whoami: jwtPayload,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return sendErrorResponse({
            event,
            error: {
                message: 'Internal Server Error',
                details: [
                    {
                        code: 0,
                        error_type: 'internal_server_error',
                        message: 'Internal Server Error',
                    },
                ],
            },
            errorCode: 500,
        });
    }
};
```

Here is my sam config

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: |
  project-server
  Sample SAM Template for project-server
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 120
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: server/
      Handler: src/app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - src/app.ts

  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ApplicationInsights-SAM-${AWS::StackName}
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName: !Ref ApplicationResourceGroup
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: true
Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value: !Sub https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello

  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
```

I have also try to add Global Api CORS in the yaml after deploy it shows internal server error

```
2023-12-04T05:59:59.443Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

2023-12-04T05:59:59.443Z undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs"," at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)"," at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)"," at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)"," at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"]}
```

```yaml
Globals:
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-access-token, jwt'"
      AllowOrigin: "'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000'"
```

I have verified that the CORS headers are being set correctly in the Lambda response. I am unsure why I am still encountering CORS issues. Is there something specific to AWS SAM or API Gateway that I might be missing in my configuration?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried several approaches to resolve this CORS issue:

Lambda Response Headers: As shown in the code snippet, I am setting the necessary CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) in the Lambda response.

Wildcard Origins: I have also set the wildcard ('*') for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow any origin. Additionally, I am dynamically checking and allowing specific origins based on the incoming request.

SAM Template CORS Configuration: In my AWS SAM template, I have checked for any specific CORS configurations, but I couldn't find any relevant settings.

Despite implementing the above, I am still facing the CORS issue when making requests from my website. I expected the CORS headers in the Lambda response to resolve this issue, but the error persists. Any insights into why the CORS headers might not be taking effect or suggestions for further troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems fine - a JS file with the code you have above results in CORS definitely being returned for me. We need to see more code as the SAM config seems to be fine.

Comment: Sure I updated the question

Comment: Now your code is not minimal haha! The key is to have a minimal example that reproduces the problem so please shorten it to something that actually reproduces it. Because with a Lambda function that just returns the headers and an OK 200 response, the above SAM config works.

Comment: You can ignore the jwt part. I tried without the JWT part but same issue